# How can I null columns in postgres db when grouping makes this the hihghes t row in grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

This table represents the artists on a music track, the **position** specifies the order of the artists and the **join_relation** specify text to be inserted between the artists such as '&' or ', ' to create an **artistcredit**

```
table "tracks_artists"
    Column     |  Type   | Modifiers
---------------+---------+-----------
 track_id      | text    | not null
 position      | integer | not null
 name          | text    |
 join_relation | text    |
```

So if we have these rows in the name

```
track_id | position | name | join_relation
--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------
f559fe60-cf21-4019-9395-7bdde3256be1 | 1 | Elec3 |  &
f559fe60-cf21-4019-9395-7bdde3256be1 | 2 | Psynina  |
```

the artistcredit would be **Elec3 & Pysnina**

but in some cases because of invalid import data we have a value for the join relation for all rows

```
track_id | position | name | join_relation
--------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------
f559fe60-cf21-4019-9395-7bdde3256be1 | 1 | Elec3 |  &
f559fe60-cf21-4019-9395-7bdde3256be1 | 2 | Psynina  | ,
```

i.e this would give **Elec3 & Pysnina ,**

but this is wrong as the highest position artist should not have a value for join_relation column

How can I fix this table so that the highest order artist for any track has the relation_join set to null. I dont mind doing this this in multiple stages if its easier.

Im using Postgres 9.3.5

**Update**
Going to break into stages based on answer below, first find the problem rows

```
create temp table badjoins as
select t1.* from tracks_artists t1
where 
( t1.join_relation is not null AND t1.join_relation!='')
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
     SELECT 1 FROM tracks_artists t2 WHERE t1.track_id = t2.track_id  
     AND t2.position > t1.position
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
UPDATE tracks_artists t1 SET join_relation = NULL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM track_artists t2 WHERE t1.track_id = t2.track_id AND t2.position > t1.position)
```

Comment: thanks think you are right, im going to put into table first to check rather than doing update straight off.